# How to explicitly call lua gc?

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

Here is my test code :

```
mt={}
myt={}
setmetatable(myt, mt)
mt.__gc=function()print("hello gc")end
myt=nil
collectgarbage()
```

But, when i running this code, there's no message print.

So, I think there must something wrong in my code.

**Update:**

```
mt.__gc=function()print("hello gc")end
setmetatable(myt, mt)
```

Set `__gc` field before `setmetatable` would solve the question(using the online [interpreter](https://www.lua.org/demo.html)), **but**, when I executing the same code through C API `luaL_dofile` in my program, `__gc` is dead again.

And I also test in my standalone lua interprete(lua 5.1.5), and '__gcc' is dead too.

The only working fine case is that online [interpreter](https://www.lua.org/demo.html) which version is 5.3.

So, I should probably ask how can I get '__gc' to work under my 5.1 version ?

Comment: `__gc` metamethod should be in metatable when you call `setmetatable`. And ofcourse it works only since Lua 5.2

Comment: `setmetatable({}, {__gc = function() print("hello gc") end})
collectgarbage()` Tested on Lua 5.2

Comment: Thanks a lot @moteus.BUT WHY?Because, when I set other elements of the metatable after I call 'setmetatable' , they all work fine, such as __index, some functions, variables...Why "GC" so special?Is there any official doc telling about this?

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.5.1

Comment: Yes, I have found this note.But, I still can not run this code correctly in my 'luaL_dofile' c api case.Is there any other note should I have to know in my case?@moteus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `__gc` field *before* calling `setmetatable`.

The [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.5.1) says:

> Note that if you set a metatable without a `__gc` field and later create that field in the metatable, the object will not be marked for finalisation.

GC methods for tables were introduced in Lua 5.2. They don't work in Lua 5.1.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed this now. But as I said in the last comment above, when running lua script through C API luaL_dofile, the GC doesn't be called with the same code above.@lhf

Comment: @francis, have you checked the return code of `luaL_dofile`? If so, post your C code.

Comment: Yes, I have.'luaL_dofile' just return 0.No error occurred.Ah, I have seen you edited your answer.And then I compared the 5.1 doc with 5.2.You are right, GC metamethod only can be used for userdata in 5.1.@thank you very much.@lhf